# Documentation Generation Error

Tags: ada, gnat-gps

I am attempting to generate the html format of some code in an attempt to save the format (font, color, size, etc) when putting it into word. The GPS IDE has the capability to generate documentation for a file, but I keep getting the following warning when running it. The result is an html file with a table of contents, but no code. I cannot find anything regarding this issue in the GPS documentation or anywhere on the internet. What does it mean when it is referring to cross-references? Any ideas on how to fix this?

```
    warning: cross references for file hello.adb are not up-to-date. Documentation not generated.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to recompile hello.adb before generating the html

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not the solution. Even disabling the "Up-to-date files only" checkbox in Edit->Preferences->Documentation still results in the same code free documentation.

Comment: Aside from changing preferences, did you compile the code and then try to generate the documentation?

Comment: @MarcC Yes - It compiles and runs fine. The error above is produced when attempting to generate the documentation after compiling/running. It is just a simple Hello World. A colleague stated that it may not be creating the documentation due to not having a .ads file associated with it?